# How to target multiple selections with xclip

Tags: command-line, copy-paste, xclip

When copying text to the clipboard, [xclip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) provides several selection targets:

```
 -selection
    specify which X selection to use, options are:
    "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), 
    "secondary" for XA_SECONDARY 
    "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Is there a way to target multiple selections?

I have tried the following options

1. `echo "Hello world" | xclip -i -selection primary -selection clipboard`
2. `echo "Hello world" | xclip -i selection primary | xclip -i selection clipboard`
3. `echo "Hello world" | xclip -i selection primary,clipboard`

but none of them worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I have tried the following options
>
> ```
> echo "Hello world" | xclip -i selection primary | xclip -i selection clipboard
> ```

You were really close there...
If you use `-f` with the first `xclip` command it will print the text back to *stdout* and you can pipe it to the second `xclip` command:

```
echo "Hello World" | xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c
```

From `man xclip`:

```
-f, -filter
            when xclip is invoked in the in mode with output level set to
            silent (the defaults), the filter option will cause xclip to print
            the text piped to standard in back to standard out unmodified
```

Comment: Thanks! I am accepting this solution because: 1) It informs about an interesting feature of xclip. 2) It allows me to pipe `xclip` commands which is quite convenient and 3) For some odd reason, it's the only answer so far that gives a working solution in my experiments for binding `copy-pipe` in `tmux` (this is what prompted this question)

Comment: If your distro provides `xsel`, an alternative to `xclip`, you can use `echo 'Hello World' | xsel -i -p && xsel -o -p | xsel -i -b`. It's slightly different and less efficient than `xclip` due to `xsel` lacking a filter option. But if you're stuck with `xsel` then this is a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use `xclip`, so there may be a way to do this natively which I'm not aware of. In any case, this should work assuming your shell is `bash`:

```
echo "Hello world" | tee >(xclip -i -selection primary) >(xclip -i -selection clipboard) >/dev/null
```

`>()` is a form of process substitution. `bash` replaces each with the path to a file descriptor which is connected to the standard input of the program within the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if that syntax compatible with `zsh` too?

Comment: @user815423426 As far as I know, yes.

Comment: I have tested here on my zsh and it works like a charm!

Comment: I've tested this on Bash on Ubuntu and openSUSE Tumbleweed.  Both seem to have a problem specifically with `xclip` in this context.  The first time it runs, only one of the selections will be correctly set (usually the secondary for me, but my understanding is that it may be non-deterministic).  The other will get the *previous* content on the other selection.  The second time it is run, since the contents are updated on the secondary, the primary is also set correctly.